# How to configure up arrow to get to the previous command in maxima?

Tags: terminal, key-mapping

If I press <kbd>Up</kbd> in a shell, then normally it brings up the previous command I entered.

In `maxima` it's all different. Pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> just prints out `^[[A`. The same thing happens when I try to move the cursor backwards (`^[[D`)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've experienced this a lot in Oracle pl/sql.
Trying installing and using rlwrap and see if it helps:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap

Comment: When you install rlwrap, I suggest also adding in the .bash_aliases or .bashrc (which ever your bash is config): `alias maxima='rlwrap maxima'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my MacOS (version 11.7.2). Installing `rlwrap` via MacPorts:

`sudo port install rlwrap`

and then adding

`alias maxima='rlwrap maxima'`

to my `.zprofile` fixed the issue.